# IP of shared server

Tags: ip

HI ,

How can I find the server IP which my shared hosting solution is on ?

Answer (score 6):

from the command line use:

```
nslookup www.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 3):

nslookup or ping (assuming windows):

```
C:\>ping -n 1 stackoverflow.com

Pinging stackoverflow.com [69.59.196.211] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 69.59.196.211: bytes=32 time=102ms TTL=106

Ping statistics for 69.59.196.211:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 102ms, Maximum = 102ms, Average = 102ms

C:\>nslookup stackoverflow.com
Server:  someserver.com
Address:  192.168.2.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    stackoverflow.com
Address:  69.59.196.211
```

Replace stackoverflow.com with the name of your server. As you can see the ip address is **69.59.196.211**

Answer (score 2):

use ping to find out IP.

note that IP doesn't have to work when accessed directly via browser etc.